# Prove this or disprove $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{b^n_{k}}{a_{k}}=\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

let $a_{i},b_{i}>0,i=1,2,\cdots,n$,

prove or disprove
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{b^n_{k}}{a_{k}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left((-1)^{n-1-k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{b^k_{i}}{a_{i}}\right)\left(\sum_{1\le t_{1}<t_{2}<\cdots\le n}\prod_{j=1}^{n-k}b_{t_{j}}\right)\right)$$

My try: I find 
when $n=1$.

$$LHS=\dfrac{b_{1}}{a_{1}}$$
$$RHS=\dfrac{b_{1}}{a_{1}}$$

But for general,I can't prove it, Thank  you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did one vote it down ?
**Hint:**
$\dfrac{b^n_{i}}{a_{i}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left((-1)^{n-1-k}\left(\dfrac{b^k_{i}}{a_{i}}\right)\left(\sum_{1\le t_{1}<t_{2}<\cdots\le n}\prod_{j=1}^{n-k}b_{t_{j}}\right)\right)$(1)

due to the fact that: $\prod_{j=1}^n (b_i-b_j)=0 \forall 1\le i \le n$

**Solution.**
We have:
$\prod_{j=1}^n (b_i-b_j)=0 \forall 1\le i \le n$
$\Leftrightarrow b^n_{i}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-1-k}.\left(\sum_{1\le t_{1}<t_{2}<\cdots\le n}\prod_{j=1}^{n-k}b_{t_{j}}\right)b^k_{i}$( **Viete**).

Thus, we obtain (1), therefore imply the equation.

Comment: Hello,can you post your solition? Thank you ,why first is hold?

Comment: I just made it more clear